# Вывод в случае or die

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
$p = $_GET['p'];
$sql = mysql_query('SELECT name,url FROM search WHERE name = "' . $p . '"') or die(mysql_error("rere"));
while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    print "<p><b>Результат поиска:</b> <a href=index.php?option=content&task=view&id=" . $r['url'] . ">" . $r['name'] . "</a>";
}
?>
```

Как вы поняли, в случае `or die` будет пустота, а я хочу, чтоб выводилась надпись `PARDON`. Как исправить `or die`? или что вообще необходимо исправить в коде?

Comment: mysql_query($query) or die!die!die!kill! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй включить:

```
// Добавлять сообщения обо всех ошибках, кроме E_NOTICE
// Это значение включено по умолчанию в php.ini
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

И для теста замени на:

$sql = mysql_query('KAKAYATO LAZA', $not_def) or die("PARDON:" . mysql_error());
```

У тебя точно нет ошибки по формату:

```
resource mysql_query ( string $query [, resource $link_identifier = NULL ] )
с  $link_identifier?
```

Я бы чуток изменил код:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

$p = $_GET['p'];

$query = sprintf("SELECT name,url FROM search WHERE name = '%s'",
    mysql_real_escape_string($p));

$sql = mysql_query($query) or die("Query_error:" . mysql_error());

while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    print "<p><b>Результат поиска:</b> <a href=index.php?option=content&task=view&id=" . $r['url'] . ">" . $r['name'] . "</a>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 or die (print"PARDON");
```

примерно вот так

Comment: не работает

Comment: а вот так or die("PARDON ");

Answer (score 1):

Вообще этот die меня всегда удивлял. Это, конечно, иногда нужно, но не стоит забывать об [обработке исключений](http://pyha.ru/articles/php/exceptions/). Прочтите, полезная информация.

Answer (score 0):

```
or die(mysql_error().' PARDON');
```

Comment: к сожалению не работает, хм, может в коде что то другое лучше исправить? а не or die?

Comment: А вы сделайте ошибку в "добровольно принудительном порядке"

    $sql = mysql_query('SELECT name,url FROM search_ERROR WHERE name = "' . $p . '"') or die(mysql_error().' PARDON');

Answer (score 0):

```
die("PARDON");
//либо
echo ("PARDON");
die(); //die();die();exit;
```